# Separation and Correlation

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, separation

In a logistic regression setting, can there be a relation between the fact that covariates are highly correlated and the problem of perfect(quasi-perfect) separation?

Comment: That's a good question, but I think one should try to formulate it in a more precise way. 
Correlation is a property of the covariates only whereas separation is a proporty of both covariates and response. So I'm pretty sure you can think of example with very correlated covariate and no separation at all and vice-versa.